# _CrtIsValidHeapPointer(block) error was raised when exit main window, after applied Singleton-Paterrn

Tags: c++, qt

I'm developing a Qt desktop app on windows.In main windows,I need to add a widget to my Tab Widget,it's usually wrote like down below:

```
void MainWindow::setConfParas()
    {
        ConfParas *confparas=new ConfParas();
        ui->TabWidget->addTab(confparas,"Configure Parameters");
    }
```

And I'm trying to apply Singleton Pattern to my `ConfParas` class, and it designs like this

```
class ConfParas : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    static ConfParas* getInstance()
    {
        static ConfParas theConfParas;
        return &theConfParas;
    }
    explicit ConfParas(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ConfParas(const ConfParas&)=delete;
    ConfParas& operator=(const ConfParas&)=delete;
    //sth else...
}
```

the former code will be wrote like:

```
void MainWindow::setConfParas()
    {
        ConfParas *confparas=ConfParas::getInstance();
        ui->TabWidget->addTab(confparas,"Configure Parameters");
    }
```

and the compiler doesn't make any error message,I can easily launch the app, but when I close the main window,**_CrtIsValidHeapPointer(block) error** was raised !!!
so I guess it happens in the period of main window **deconstructing**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you pass a pointer to a `QObject`, Qt takes over the lifetime of that pointer. It assumes the memory was dynamically allocated, and then calls `delete` when it's time to deallocate. An exception to this rule is if a child is destroyed before its parent.

Refer to https://doc.qt.io/archives/4.6/objecttrees.html

Your static member is declared on the stack, and is managed by the runtime. When you pass it to a `QObject`, you're begging for a double-delete. That is, you call [`QTabWidget::AddTab`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qtabwidget.html#addTab) which delegates ownership to the `QTabWidget`. This `QTabWidget`, a non-static variable will be destroyed before any static variables (your `QWidget`). Since it is the parent, it will also delete its children (your `QWidget`), and then when `main` ends it will also call the destructor of your `static QWidget`, hence a double-delete.

If you made your static member a pointer that was allocated on first call, then you wouldn't have this problem. In fact, I know some developers that would say this isn't really a problem anyway (not saying I agree with them) because what's the point of cleaning a building before you demolish it?

Comment: actually I've tried to do as you said, make a static private member pointer and allocate it on first call and return a pointer ,but the compiler always gives me LKN2001 error........

Comment: @陈裘凯: If you update your question with an exact error message and accompanying code that reproduces it, I maybe able to help.

Comment: I've solved this issue... I forget to initialize the static member pointer to nullptr in cpp file, there is must sth wrong with my brain.....anyway, many many thankssssss